# Homogenizing a smooth affine curve

Tags: algebraic-geometry, algebraic-curves

Given a smooth affine curve $C$ with some equation, say, $C: 3x^3 + 4y^3 + 5 = 0$, we can homogenize it to obtain a smooth projective curve $\bar{C} : 3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3=0$ which is compact.

Much like the projectivization of the affine line $\mathbb{A}^1$ to obtain $\mathbb{P}^1$, we add a point at infinity to projectivize $C$. I would like to know if all projectivization of smooth affine curves are done by simply adding one point at infinity, i.e., are there examples where it's done by adding more than a point? I'm referring only to curves of course.

Comment: It's not obvious to me that homogenising the defining equation preserves smoothness...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not even true in that specific example that you're only adding one point at infinity: the part of that curve at infinity is given by $V(3X^3+4Y^3+5Z^3)\cap V(Z)=V(3X^3+4Y^3,Z)$ which is three points, $[1:\sqrt[3]{\frac34}:0]$, $[1:\omega\sqrt[3]{\frac34}:0]$, and $[1:\omega^2\sqrt[3]{\frac34}:0]$ where $\omega$ is a primitive cube root of unity.

The general situation is that for any smooth projective curve, any nonempty proper open subvariety is affine, so by starting with a projective curve and removing an arbitrary finite number of points $n$ we may find a smooth affine curve so that the (smooth) projectivization needs $n$ additional points to be added to the curve.

Let me also warn you that it is frequently false that the projectivization of a smooth affine curve is a smooth projective curve: for instance, $y=x^3$ which is smooth projectivizes to $YZ^2=X^3$ which has a cusp at $[0:1:0]$.

Comment: The second paragraph you wrote was what led me to ask this question actually. I know that given any smooth projective curve, the removal of a finite number of points will make the resulting curve smooth affine. So I was wondering if adding a point at infinity to any smooth affine curve would make it a smooth projective one. Thankfully it's not, otherwise curves of the form $C \backslash \{p_1,p_2\}$ with $C$ projective would NOT have its projectivization to be $C$, which was the confusion I had. Thank you, it helped a lot.

Comment: Just one question though, the addition of finite number of points to a smooth affine curve to obtain its smooth projectivization retains the genus right? Same for the removal of a finite number of points from a smooth projective curve.

Comment: Well, what do you mean when you say genus? If you're talking about geometric genus, then yes, since it's *defined* to be the genus of the smooth projective model and therefore it's a birational invariant.